# Is it possible to convert a AVCHD video stored in a MTS file loss-less without recoding into a Blue-Ray video disk?

Tags: avchd

And if so which application is able to do that? I do not need menus.

Right now I copy the MTS files directly to a BD data disk, which can be played by a PS3. But I would prefer a standard BD video disk. But I do not want to recode the data. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, here is a list of applications on PC and MAC that open MTS files and can convert them to a more desirable file format.

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/mts

Comment: I can open the files already with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). This was not the question.

Comment: Yea actually it does, you can use Toast to open the file then burn it to a BluRay Disc...or Roxio Creater on PC...you can also use any of those programs to convert the file as well